# How can I redirect all pages to https, using .htaccess, with exceptions?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, ssl

I have used htaccess to force all pages to re route to https using...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://ourdomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Is there any way I can reverse that rule for ourdomain.com/videos && ourdomain.com/blog making sure that these pages are forced to drop the https and use http?

Answer (score 6):

You're already part way there with your use of `RewriteCond` to restrict the rewrites to requests on port 80.

You do *not* want to rewrite requests on port 80 for `/videos` and `/blog`, so:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/videos
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://ourdomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

And you want to rewrite requests for these URLs on port (presumably) 443:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteRule ^/((videos|blog)/.*) http://ourdomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm getting spme strange behaviour with both solutions... If I go to https://domain.com/blog or /videos it doesnt redirect and keeps the https if I go to http://domain.com/videos or /blog it directs back to the homepage https://domain.com

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteRule ^blog/?(.*) http://ourdomain.com/blog/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteRule ^videos/?(.*) http://ourdomain.com/videos/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/videos
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://ourdomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

one more solution. I hope it may help.

```
RewriteEngine on
Rewritebase /


RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off [OR]
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^(/(.*))?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```